# How come link to the protoype is lost?

Tags: javascript

How come one pattern works and the other doesnt? In the second code the link to the prototype is lost,is there any way of estabilishing the link to the prototype using the second pattern?Or am I doing it wrong?

This Works

```
function Robot() {
    this.weapons=5;
    this.lives=5;
}

Robot.prototype.fireWeapon=function(){alert('weapons fired');};

var a=new Robot();
a.fireWeapon();
```

This doesnt work

```
function Robot() {

    var weapons=5;
    var lives=10;

    return {
        weapons: weapons,
        lives : lives
    };
}

Robot.prototype.fireWeapon=function(){alert('weapons fired');};

var a=new Robot();
a.fireWeapon();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it in the second example you don't have a `Robot`, you have an `Object`.

By returning a new anonymous object, you override the expression that would be assigned to `a` by default, which is the `Robot`.

Try this line in each and you will see:

```
alert(a.constructor);
```

For the first one, you will see `Object` and the second, you will see the `Robot` function.

Answer (score 1):

A javascript class should **not** `return` anything!

And if it does, then it is equal to whatever it returns and it is not a prototype class.

See the log for both of your functions: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/UreSA/